# return csv.writer(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds) TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
haotou = int(input("head number "))
yyrangest2 = int(input("start of the middle number"))
yyrangeen2 = int(input("end of the middle number"))
while wan <= 1002:
    for xx in range(0000, 10000):
        for yy in range(yyrangest2, yyrangeen2):
            xxy = str(xx).zfill(4)
            yyy = str(yy).zfill(4)
            print(haotou, yyy, xxy, sep="")
            data = pd.DataFrame({'head': [haotou] , 'middle': [yy], 'the third part': [xx]})
            data.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, sep='')
            wan = wan + 1
```

and the error is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/guess.py", line 16, in 
    data.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, sep='')
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 200, in save
    self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 517, in UnicodeWriter
    return csv.writer(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Comment: the Chinese phone number system is separated as 3 parts

Comment: first part is the provider second part is the region third part is random

Comment: I want to wrote a script that can find someones phone number by the provider and location ,so I can export It into a csv file to put it in my Contacts list so the social soft ware can get tricked and thought that I knew him and to give me his account for me to confirm

Comment: if I change it into  data = pd.DataFrame({'号头': [haotou] , '号段': [yyy], '号尾巴': [xxy]}) it will be 
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 200, in save
    self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/my day/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 517, in UnicodeWriter
    return csv.writer(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Comment: you can't use empty string as separator - `sep=''`. It has to be `1-character string` - ie `sep=','`

Comment: it is nice but now it only gives the final answer

Comment: but what if I wanted to have the entire printed things

Comment: you should create empty DataFrame before `while` loop (not inside), add elements to this `DataFrame` inside `while` loop, and save it after `while` loop (not inside)

Comment: if you want it without separator then you should keep all in one column - but then you don't even need `DataFrame` because you can save it using standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`. Or maybe you should use space `sep=' '` as separator - it is also 1-character string. `csv` means `comma separated values` but it can use other separator instead of comma but it still has to be `separated values`

Comment: I am really sorry to ask but can you show me how it is done

Comment: I have only learned python in a short time  by my self

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.append([{'seq': zz,'hao': haotou,'middle': yyy,'third': xxy}],ignore_index=True,sort=False) 
data.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, sep=" ")
```

use this instead and save outside of the loop